# ASP.NET MVC Deployment to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, deployment

So I'm trying to deploy a test site to Azure.

The site has a database which was built in SQL server management studios, then I used ADO.NET Entity Data model to import the database into visual studios. Then I just used scaffolding to create CRUD operations.

How do I deploy this web app to Azure? 
I used a database first so I'm not sure if that's a problem

I've tried following some tutorials but they seem to have different UI

eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/publish-to-azure

Comment: Following gives a bit more of an updated process - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

First you want to go into Tools in your nav menu and check for 'Get Tools And Features'. Make sure you have Azure tools installed, and from there you'll be able to access the Azure menu to publish your web app directly from Visual Studio. You can also do this in VS Code, however you'll need the official Azure extension from Microsoft.